# How to scale custom shape physics body with physics editor

Tags: physics, game-physics, coronasdk

I am facing an issue, that is, I have several physics bodies who's shapes are defined in Physics Editor, and I am using that's .lua file for shape. But I am not able to find that how can I apply Scaling on X and Y axes separately??
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Physics Editor** by *Andreas Loew / code-and-web.de*

You can try this code

This is the implementation

```
local scaleX = 0.5
local scaleY = 0.2
local physicsData = (require ("your.physics.object")).physicsData(scaleX,scaleY) --This is the scaling of the physics body
object = display.newImage("youimage.png")
object.xScale = scaleX
object.yScale = scaleY
physics.addBody( object, "static", physicsData:get("physics_dody") )
```

On the Physics Editor Lua(your .lua shape), you must change the following following code

```
function M.physicsData(scale)
```

to

```
function M.physicsData(scaleX,scaleY)
```

**and**

```
local s = scale or 1.0
for bi,body in pairs(physics.data) do
    for fi,fixture in ipairs(body) do
        if(fixture.shape) then
            for ci,coordinate in ipairs(fixture.shape) do
                fixture.shape[ci] = s * coordinate
            end
        else
            fixture.radius = s * fixture.radius
        end
    end
end
```

to

```
local sX = scaleX or 1.0
local sY = scaleY or 1.0
for bi,body in pairs(physics.data) do
    for fi,fixture in ipairs(body) do
        if(fixture.shape) then
            for ci,coordinate in ipairs(fixture.shape) do
                if (ci%2) == 0 then
                    fixture.shape[ci] = sX * coordinate
                else
                    fixture.shape[ci] = sY * coordinate
                end
            end
        else
            fixture.radius = sX * fixture.radius
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is uniform scaling, what if I want to apply different scale factors on X and Y?
For example: xScale = 1 and yScale = 1.2

Comment: I edit my whole answer, you can now use it.
I hope this will help

Comment: Thank you so much
I have just inverted sX and sY
Now it works perfect :)